# Send URL link of discussion board topic in an email from Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-discussion-board

I have set up a Sharepoint 2007 Discussion Board. I want to create a workflow that sends and email to the creator of a topic within the discussion board when there is a reply on the topic. I want the email to contain a link to the discussion topic - the user can click the link see the original topic as well as the replies.

I managed to create a workflow in sharepoint designer which emails the original creator when there is a new reply BUT i cannot get a link to the topic.

I have tried using (http://servername-etc/Topic Subject) which I can correctly outputs as text, however when I try enclosing this in  tags it breaks; the link contains spaces and SPD doesn't seem to like that.

Is there a better way to send a link of the current discussion topic via email?????

EDIT: to get the url in sharepoint designer, I currently use http://server/[%listName:Path%] - this doesn't seem to be the ideal approach though

Comment: Would You mind to use jQuery to do this?

Comment: Did you try using %20 instead of spaces?

Comment: @ricardordz - I would prefer SPD if possible but I think it *should* be ok to use JQuery, not sure how this can be achieved though.

Comment: hi @Steve, via jQuery you could  add an event to your "save comment" button, then fire a "send email" function (this could live in a hidden webpart, some C# coding or maybe VB), with your url, comment id and other stuff as parameter. Just in case SPD is not working properly.

Comment: Thanks - How would I attach an event? Sorry, I am quite new to SharePoint ... I am guessing I cannot attach an event via SPD...

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same in SharePoint Designer 2010 and used the Field from source: "URL Path". "Encode Absolute URL" also does the trick.

Comment: URL path is available in 2010 workflows, but not in 2013, just in case anybody wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

Probably he can subscribe to the alerts or you can programatically subscribe him to alerts in the event handler for your discussion board.

Answer (score 0):

To get a link to list items I use

```
To view the request, click <a href="SITE URL/Lists/LISTNAME/DispForm.aspx?ID=ID LOOKUP ">here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

We still use SP 2007 here and I ran into this problem where I needed to have the workflow email a link to the discussion topic in either flat or thread view. I got around this by requesting data from myself in the workflow prior to sending the notification. And I store that as a variable to then use in the notification email. Perfect workaround!